# Java NIO UDP - Selector Hangs when trying to register

Tags: java, udp, nio

```
final DatagramChannel dc = DatagramChannel.open();
        dc.configureBlocking(false);
        dc.socket().bind(localAddress);
        final SelDatagramChannel c = new SelDatagramChannel(dc, datagramListener);
--->>>>        final SelectionKey sk = dc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

The market line hangs forever when you try to register a DatagramChannel.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I think you will need to post a more complete code sample to give  some context to your question.

Answer (score 1):

There's some chat in http://echelog.matzon.dk/logs/browse/java/1276898400 which mentions that `dc.register()` must be called in the selection thread. The JavaDoc doesn't seem very specific about that, though.

I guess you do that by putting in a list somewhere, and calling `selector.wakeup()`. But I'm still having timing glitches where it's unclear how long before the register succeeds...

Comment: This idea in general worked for me. @DavidVanBrink Maybe you can post some code and ask for this to become the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending a CTRL+BREAK to the JVM to get a [thread dump](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the above code executed in the thread which does selection? I think we need to register the channels with Selector in the same thread which does selection.